# Is it posible to created an in app purchase library

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

the idea is to develop a library to allow other apps to pay with my method inside their apps. This method of payment is completly independent from paypal, google play in app billing, etc... Do you think there must any problem to publish their apps on Google Play?

Regards.

Comment: I don't think it will be a problem. A lot of app already use diffrent payment system.

Comment: Which apps use a non-Google Play payment system?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Play Developer Program Policies, no.

https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

"In-store purchases: Developers charging for apps and downloads from Google Play **must use Google Play’s payment system**."

"In-app purchases: Developers offering products within a game downloaded from Google Play or providing access to game content **must use Google Play In-app Billing as the method of payment**."

So yes, there will be a problem publishing apps on Google Play. They will eventually catch on and ban your application.